# How compiler knows whether the running code is Managed or UnManaged in .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, unmanaged, managed

When reading about the basics of `.NET` like `Managed and Unmanaged code`, the code which runs under `CLR and developed in .NET framework is managed` while `unmanaged does not run under CLR and developed outside the .NET framework`. `Moreover`, thinking and knowing about the `practicalities` about the codes and `how they run` and `how the compiler knows the type` of code was a `bit confusing`. So, to get rid of this confusion, felt to ask this on here.

Please let me know about this.

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: which compiler? as far as csc is concerned, it is always targeting a managed platform (MSIL). That IL *might* be converted later (IL2CPP etc). Or do you mean the C++ compiler?

Comment: @MarcGravell Nope not C++ compiler. Compiler within .NET

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about the compilers for languages such as C#, VB(.NET) etc, then: from the compiler's perspective they are *always* managed. Everything they output is managed code, i.e. IL. There are places where C# etc get *close* to directly unmanaged - for example:

- when using `unsafe` code and "unmanaged pointers", C# can talk directly to unmanaged memory - but it always expresses *how* to do that via IL (IL contains operators for dealing with raw pointers)
- P/Invoke layers can express boundaries for talking to external unmanaged code

However, in both cases it is the JIT compiler at runtime (or the AOT compiler if using a non-JIT target platform) that interprets these unmanaged intents *expressed in IL*, and outputs the CPU intrinsics to implement them. But... that's exactly what the JIT / AOT does for *all* IL, so ... nothing different there.

So: from the perspective of a compiler for a language such as C# / VB(.NET), there is no actual question here: it is *always* working 100% managed in terms of the output - and since the compilers are (since Roslyn) *also* .NET code, they are 100% managed in terms of their actual execution too.

If you meant something different, it would be worth clarifying the question, being *really, really specific* about what scenario(s) you have in mind, preferably with examples.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Moreover, could you please elaborate on the flow how managed code differs from unmanaged while executing [pictorial if possible].

Comment: @PPB you asked about the compiler, so ... that isn't relevant. And at runtime, the purpose of the JIT is to turn IL into opcodes suitable for the CPU, so... the JIT output is just regular opcodes. Again, the question you're asking doesn't really make sense. So I'm curious as to what it is that you *actually* want to know...